# Why is RuntimeBinderException thrown when trying to invoke an internal method that has dynamic parameters?

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic-typing

I'm developing an application in C# and in one of my projects I define an interface:

```
internal interface IArticleResolver
{
    string Resolve(string article, dynamic context);

    void TestMethod();
}
```

Within the same project I implement this interface as below:

```
internal class ArticleResolver : IArticleResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string article, dynamic context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        // Pass through.
    }
}
```

This project exposes its internals to a unit test library within the same solution. Within that unit test library, I define the following test:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(Examples))]
internal void Article_Resolver_Should_Resolve_Article_From_Context_As_Expected(
    string unresolvedArticle,
    dynamic context,
    string expectedResolvedArticle)
{
    // WHEN we resolve the article using the given context.
    this.articleResolver.TestMethod();
    string actualResolvedArticle = this.articleResolver.Resolve(unresolvedArticle, context);

    // THEN the article should have been resolved as expected.
    actualResolvedArticle.ShouldBe(expectedResolvedArticle);
}
```

What I find is that `this.articleResolver.TestMethod()` gets invoked without problem, as I expect. However, `this.articleResolver.Resolve(...)` causes a `RuntimeBindingException` to be thrown *even though it's at the same level of accessibility*. The full message is:

> 'Mofichan.Library.IArticleResolver.Resolve(string, object)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

The only special thing about this method is that it accepts a dynamic parameter, which I'm assuming is the cause. If I make `IArticleResolver` public, I find that `NotImplementedException` gets thrown instead (as expected).

Is there a reason why dynamic properties would cause this behaviour and if so, is there a way I can test this code without making the interface or implementing class public?

**Edit 1**

In case it's useful information, I'm developing this application against .NET Core SDK 1.1 and right now I'm testing it on a Windows 10 machine.

**Edit 2**

I did some further testing and I'm discovering some interesting results. It seems that `RuntimeBinderException` is only thrown if you're passing an object with static type `dynamic` to the method:

```
// WHEN we resolve the article using the given context.
this.articleResolver.TestMethod();
this.articleResolver.Resolve(unresolvedArticle, "foo"); // NotImplementedException
this.articleResolver.Resolve(unresolvedArticle, new ExpandoObject()); // NotImplementedException
this.articleResolver.Resolve(unresolvedArticle, (dynamic)new ExpandoObject()); // RuntimeBinderException
string actualResolvedArticle = this.articleResolver.Resolve(unresolvedArticle, context);
```

**Edit 3**

I no longer get `RuntimeBinderException` after changing the `context` parameter of the unit test method to its actual static type (`ExpandoObject`):

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(Examples))]
internal void Article_Resolver_Should_Resolve_Article_From_Context_As_Expected(
    string unresolvedArticle,
    ExpandoObject context,
    string expectedResolvedArticle)
{
    // WHEN we resolve the article using the given context.
    string actualResolvedArticle = this.articleResolver.Resolve(unresolvedArticle, context);

    // THEN the article should have been resolved as expected.
    actualResolvedArticle.ShouldBe(expectedResolvedArticle);
}
```

The method under test itself remains unchanged:

```
internal class ArticleResolver : IArticleResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string article, dynamic context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

While this technically means I no longer have a problem, I'm still very curious about why this happens.

Comment: The declaration of `articleResolver` is not shown. It is declared as `dynamic`?

Comment: @mikez It's declared as `private readonly IArticleResolver articleResolver` within the unit test class and instantiated within the class constructor as `this.articleResolver = new ArticleResolver();`.